# I am having problems with arrays in my code. Any suggestions?

Tags: c++, arrays

Here is my code for my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int input1[8];
    int input2[8];
    int output[8];

    cout << "Welcome to binary calculator!" << endl;
    cin >> input1[8];
    cin >> input2[8];
    if(input1[0]+input2[0]>1){
        output[8] = 0;
        if(input1[1]+input2[1]>1){
            output[7] = 0;
            cout << output[7] << output[8] << endl;
        }
    }else{
        output[8]=input1[8]+input2[8];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that on the line where the 8th element of output is supposed to equal the sum of the 8th element of input1 and the 8th element of input2. I tried to put seven because I thought I remembered that was how indexing for arrays worked but I was wrong, and now I am stuck.

Comment: `cin >> input1[8];` `cin >> input2[8];` ... `output[8] = 0;` are out of bounds.

Comment: If 0 is the first element, which element is 8?

Comment: Consider picking a question title that is actually helpful. As written currently, it is devoid of any useful information.

Comment: Don't use [magic numbers](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MagicNumber), prefer using `#define` identifiers.  This allows for one place to change the array capacity instead of searching all of your code (and maybe changing a wrong constant).

Comment: You only input one element into both arrays.  Why do you need an array?

Comment: If you are going to use arrays, you need to initialize all the slots that you use.  For example, you don't assign any values into slots 0 and 1.  Most programs use a loop to read the values into the array.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to manipulate the 8th element of an array, it should be accessed using input1[7]/input2[7], as the array index always start from 0.

Please elaborate more as to what exactly is the problem you are facing.

Comment: What's there to elaborate? The code exhibits undefined behavior. Game over.

Comment: @IInspectable Completely agree! Still wanted to get proper info out from the problem facing guy, so that can be of some help.

Comment: What information do you need? There is only one solution: Fix the bug. It doesn't matter what observable side effect this particular instance of undefined behavior exposes on this particular developer's machine, running their particular OS, and using their particular compiler. How would a hypothetical answer, that their display turns red help you suggest a solution. How would your solution be different, if the display turned blue instead?

Comment: _"array index usually start from 0"_ - In C++ array indexes are zero based so I don't know what you mean by _usually_.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious yes it is "Always"! thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Are you supposed to read in integers and manipulate the *bits*?

Bit manipulation, or *twiddling*, is performed using the *binary* operators: `&, |, ~, ^, +, and -`.

See also: [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) which helps treat a number as a container of bits.

Binary arithmetic is too large of a concept to explain in a Stack Overflow answer; search the internet for "C++ binary arithmetic tutorial".

Comment: While `~`, `+`, and `-` do alter the bit patterns, they aren't commonly referred to as *bitwise operators* (which, I assume, is what you really meant by saying *"binary operators"*).